# how to insert row only once and make it updatable forever after

Tags: php, mysql, row

I am working on source code where there is a table called tvseries (id = foreign key, tvs_id = primary key). what i want to achieve is that when user gets logged in for first time and submit a form related to tv series info it should insert a new row in table with related data but when again user submits that form it shouldn't create new row instead it should update the existing row.

Simply, only first time when user submits form it should insert details submitted and afterwards it should be updated whenever submitted.(i just want only one row to be inserted and latter updated with that form).

I have written a code which only inserts a new row with related data each time it is submitted

This is my code (Insertion part)

```
        $query = "INSERT INTO Tvseries SET Tvseries_fav=?, Tvseries_rank=?, Tvseries_rewatch=?, 
        Tvseries_status=?, Tvseries_rec=?, id=?";

        $stmt = $conn->prepare($query);
        $stmt->bind_param('siissi', $tvsfav, $tvsrank, $tvsrewatched, $tvsstatus, $tvsrecommend, $id);
        $result = $stmt->execute();

        if ($result) {
            $tvs_id = $stmt->insert_id;
            $stmt->close();
            $_SESSION['message'] = 'Details have been submitted successfully!';
            $_SESSION['type'] = 'alert-success';
            header('location: Tvseriesinfo.php');
        } else {
            $_SESSION['error_msg'] = "Database error: Could not update details";
        }
    }
```

Extra info :
I have another table called users (where id = primary key), 
Am using session variables.

How should i change my code so that i can achieve my objective which is mentioned in first two paragraphs.
I have searched stack overflow for related solution but haven't found satisfactory solution. Any help from you will be appreciated.

And one more thing my form contains only selcect boxes.

Thank you

Comment: Just `SELECT` it first and check if it exists, if not `INSERT` it, else `UPDATE` it. This way you have total control over it. You could use `INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE ...` aswell, but I suggest the first route for clarity.

Comment: I'd suggest the second approach for tolerance of race conditions.

Comment: @cckep Thank you for responding, yeah insert ... on duplicate key update ... was in my mind too but actually i don't know how to use it in my source code. If you don;t mind can i know how to use insert on duplicate key update in my existing code

Comment: I have researched a lot on Insert ... on duplicate key update ... but didn't found an answer to how can i include it inside my code and obtain desired result

Comment: What would an update look like? A total row replacement? Do the fields listed represent all of the columns of the `Tvseries` table? It looks like its missing a `user_id` value, and I'd assume that (`user_id`, `tv_series_id`) is the unique value and that (in combined form), should be the primary key.

Comment: @danblack Thank for your response, yes the fields mentioned represents all the columns in Tvseries table and yes i want total row replacement and actually there is column called id : (which is users id(pk) in users table and foreign key in tv series table) and tv_series_id is (pk) in tv series table

Comment: right ok. Easier than `IODKU` is [REPLACE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/replace.html) which be warned has total row replacement schematics, so only good if they are all fields, however for the most part, is identical to `INSERT`. There might have been another caveat, but I can't see it in the docs. Someone will probably correct me soon of it if there was.